# Firebase - child_added being called on delete of item

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of `post`'s and I'm fetching them with `.on('child_added')` the problem is that I only want to get the `post`'s when an item is *added* and not when it is *removed*, however, it seems that `.on('child_added')` gets called even when a post is removed. Which is not what I need in my case.

Here is my function:

```
if(fromClick) { this.subscription.off(); this.firstRun = true;}
this.postFeed = new Array();
this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
   .orderByChild('created')
   .limitToLast(10);

this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
   this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val());
});
```

So it displays last `10` and then when an item is added it adds that to the array as well, but when an item is removed it gets called again..

How can I prevent this? So that the call only happens for `post`'s that are added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling:

```
this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
   .orderByChild('created')
   .limitToLast(10);
```

You are creating a query that contains the 10 most recent posts. If you remove one of those, another one becomes the 10th most recent posts, so you get a `child_added` for that.

The only thing I can imagine is only getting the 10 once, and then doing a `limitToLast(1)`:

```
this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
   .orderByChild('created')
   .limitToLast(10)
   .once("value", function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(child) {       
       // These are the initial 10 children
     });
   });
this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
   .orderByChild('created')
   .limitToLast(1)
   .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
     // This is the latest child, but this will also fire when you remove the current latest
   });
```